# Left and right keys acting crazy?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, keyboard, hp

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Remix on my HP Mini 1000. Everything worked fine right up until I tried typing - apparently the left and right arrow keys on my keyboard are uncontrollable. Everything I type ends up looking messed up because the left and right keys keep automatically inserting themselves into everything I type.

This also happens when I click on, say, "File" on Firefox. It starts rotating between all the different menu options even though I'm not pressing anything on the keyboard.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Is this a problem with the keyboard itself?

Comment: First keys that broken on my notebook, was arrows too. But try another OS or LiveCD for sure

Answer (score 1):

I think its an issue with the hardware. But you may also check 'Applications' > 'Keyboard' (under System).

There you can check the configuration and see if there is anything making your arrow keys go crazy (though I guess You have tried that already).

Also here is what I might have done; flip the netbook upside down and give it a little hard pat right behind those arrow keys. It **might** fix if there is something stuck in those nerdy keys of yours **(CAUTION: THIS WAY IS SOMETHING WHICH I AM TELLING YOU AND NOT SUGGESTING OR RECOMMENDING. DO IT AT YOUR OWN WILL)**

One way how you can ensure if its a hardware issue is that you can try Ubuntu or any other OS on this netbook of yours by booting it off a USB Stick. Dont install but just try some other OS and if it will act crazy again, you will know that this is something with the hardware.

Hope this helps.